# Iterate over a list which contains dictionary names

Tags: python

I have a list which contains the names of different dictionaries. I want to iterate over those names and get the key and value of each of the dictionaries.

For eg:

```
    ver=['one','two','three']
    for v in ver:
        for k,v in v.iteritems():
            print k,v
```

where one, two, three are separate dictionaries. I need key, values from all the dictionaries.
But i am getting below error while doing this.
AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'",)

Comment: you are iterating over strings, not dictionaries, so you can't access the contents this way. `for d in (one, two, three): for k, v in d.iteritems(): print k, v` Also, avoid re-using the v variable name within your inner loop

Comment: Sorry i forgot about this

Comment: @Andrew it's possible using globals() or locals() which return a dictionary of global / local attributes. I'm not saying one should do it this way, but it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting @ApplePie, I definitely should have said "shouldn't" as you've indicated. I suppose technically, he could also use `eval("one")` as well, although with the same "shouldn't really" tag applied

Comment: @Andrew thanks didn't think about that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for some reason, you must use strings as you are doing. You can invoke `globals()` which keeps tracks over global variables or `locals()`, which keeps track of local variables like so:

```
>>> one = {'1': 1}
>>> two = {'2': 2}
>>> three = {'3': 3}
>>> ver = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> locals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'a': 1, 'one': {'1': 1}, 'two': {'2': 2}, 'three': {'3': 3}, 'ver': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'v': 'three'}
>>> for v in ver:
...     print(globals()[v].items())
... 
dict_items([('1', 1)])
dict_items([('2', 2)])
dict_items([('3', 3)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing strings with the actual dicts.

Here is what you are actually looking for.

```
one = {1:9}
two = {'zz':34}
three = {}
ver = [one,two,three]
for v in ver:
  for k,v in v.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in python are not enclosed with quotes. So instead define ver as:

```
ver = [one, two, three]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most maintainable way to do what you require is to have them as keys of another dictionary, for example:

```
data = {
    'one': {4:5, 'foo':'bar'},
    'two': {1:'baz'},
    'three': {'x':'y', 'a':'b'}
}


ver = ['one','two','three']
for x in ver:
    for k,v in data[x].items():
        print(k,v)
```

If you have them as separate variables, you could always start by constructing such a dictionary, as:

```
data = {
    'one': one,
    'two': two,
    'three': three
}
```

Accessing variables dynamically by name is possible by use of the `globals` function, but in most cases this is less useful than organising your data in such a way as to make such an approach unnecessary.